# Why does using const in a for-of loop in global scope throw TypeError, but within a function it works?

Tags: javascript, constants, typeerror

```
var tests = [1, 4, 3];
for(const test of tests){
  test += 1;
  console.log(test);
}
```

**-we get a type error b/c of const**

```
function average(...nums){
  let sum = 0;
  let counter = 0;
  for(const num of nums){
    sum += num;
    counter++;
  }
  return sum / counter;
}

console.log(average(5, 5));
```

**-why don't we get a type error here since we used const again**

Comment: The first one you got type error because you are changing the `const test` by `test += 1`.

The second one, you are not changing value of `const num` so it is fine.

Comment: you can do it by assigning the `test` to another variable and use it instead of `test`. for eg : `temp = test; temp += 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are reassigning to constant in the first and not in the second. You mutate `test` with `test += 1` which is illegal whereas you never mutate `num`. If you try `num += 1` in the second, you'll have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused with which variable is being changed. 
The first one you are changing the value of `const test` but in the second example you are changing the value of `let sum`

`sum += num;` is same as `sum = sum + num` num did not change

`test += 1;` is the same as `test = test + 1`